# How to tint an Android bitmap in White?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to colorize a bitmap into different colors.
Thanks to [this SE question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/how-do-i-blend-a-bitmap-with-a-color) i am able to tint my it into different colors when i draw it on my canvas.

```
Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 1);
p.setColorFilter(filter);
```

But this seems to not work with `Color.WHITE` (maybe because my bitmap is colorized in only 1 color).
I want to have a white shape of the original bitmap (only transparent + white)

Comment: why do you need Paint? can you use   `your_drawable_image.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: Thank @essess for your answer, but i need a bitmap because i also apply other modifications to this bitmap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. I reply here for people who might face this problem.

In order to keep the shape of a bitmap, and colorize it you need to use a `PorterDuffColorFilter` instead of the `LightingColorFilter` i used initially.

```
 filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
 mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
```

The second parameter is a `PorterDuff.Mode`,  you can find the complete list [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)